# Eclipse - No tests found with test runner 'JUNIT 4'

Tags: spring, eclipse, junit

I have generated a spring boot project from start.spring.io and imported it into STS. The tutorial  I'm watching wants to run a JUNIT test before continuing. But when I try to run Junit test I get the following error "No tests found with test runner 'JUNIT 4'.

Also tested with following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

I suspect `class DevopsApplicationTests`. If I add `class DevopsApplicationTests extends TestCase` then unit test works but fails. Not sure what should be the correct code.

[image]

When testing "import org.junit.Test" I see the following errors.

[image]

When trying "import junit.framework.Test;" Also I get "No tests found with test runner 'JUNIT 4' like before but also there is a error near "@Test".

[image]

Comment: Java 5? JUnit 3? Is what you have chosen really what you want? The project folder has an error marker, which means that there are errors which you ignore.

Comment: what needs to be done? I'm trying to re-import and check the errors. still junit error isn't related to the project error right?

Comment: I guess you missed to specify the Java version in your `pom.xml`, so Java 5 will be used. See in _Problems_ view for the list of errors. By the way, your Eclipse looks outdated. Therefore, it could also be the case that you are using a newer Java and the root cause is that you have missed to upgrade Eclipse.

Comment: Pom.xml has Java 11 mentioned in there. not sure why its using java 5

Comment: Upgrade your Eclipse and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is a separate Stack Exchange for [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Hi, I've fixed the errors. But still can't run junit test.

Comment: You screenshot shows you have JUnit 3 as dependency, which is probably wrong. You should have JUnit, probably 4 or 5, as a Maven dependency instead.

Comment: Tested it with dependency as well. Updated the question. Still same issue

Comment: Did you also update your JUnit run configuration (in the _Test_ tab you have to choose as _Test runner:_ _JUnit 4_)?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong import.

`org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` is the annotation for JUnit 5.

For JUnit 4, you need to `import junit.framework.Test`.

By the way, the latest version of STS is 3.8.0, released in 2017, based on Eclipse Neon from 2016.

STS is deprecated, and is replaced by 'Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse': https://spring.io/tools

Comment: `import org.junit.Test` seems to work but unit test is failing though. I've also posted the output of Junit 4 import. Can you please check?

Comment: The errors you get are because JUnit 4 didn't support testing non-public methods. You probably copy-pasted this from someone who was using JUnit 5. I recommend you drop STS, start with the new Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse, and run with JUnit 5.

Comment: okay is `import org.junit.Test;` junit 3 method? is the test result something that can be fixed? I'm still new to this so don't want to divert from the tutor's methods.

Answer (score 0):

Making the class Public fixed the issue.

```
package com.example.devops;

// import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
public class DevopsApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```